# Return Strings from Table in Row Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Let's say I create a `table` in HTML which contains a background colour and text. Essentially I want to extract that text from the table using JS in row-major order as long as the text colour doesn't match the background colour.

For example, say this is my table:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Build a table</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="test.js"></script>
  <table>
          <tbody>
          <tr>
              <td style="color: #ff00ff; background-color:#FFFFFF">Q</TD>
              <td style="background-color: #442244; color: #442244">Y</td>
              <td style="color: #FFFF00; background-color:#442244">A</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <td style="color: #FFEEFE; background-color:#990000">Q</td>
              <td style="color: #FFFF00; background-color:#FF0">M</td>
              <td style="color: #000000; background-color:#FF7777">O</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
      <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
```

I'd get a 3x2 table.
So now I want to get the output to be a concatenated string such as
`QAQO` since Y and M are invisible

Obviously I need to create a function in JS and I have looked around But i'm not sure what to exactly search when it comes to extracting text from a table and printing it out whilst concatenating

test.js

```
function getText() {

  var arr = $('td').map(function() {
  let $td = $(this);
  return $td.css('background-color') !== $td.css('color') ? $td.text() : null;}).get();

  console.log(arr.join(''));
  $('#result').text(arr.join(''));
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) - you can use it to get all the `td`elements so you can compare the colours and get the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop through each row and find the `td` where the `background-color` is different to the `color`.

The simplest way to do that would be to use `map()` to build an array of the values which you can then loop through, or concatenate as needed:

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var arr = $('td').map(function() {
    let $td = $(this);
    return $td.css('background-color') !== $td.css('color') ? $td.text() : null;
  }).get();

  console.log(arr.join(''));
  $('#result').text(arr.join(''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #ff00ff; background-color: #FFFFFF;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #442244; background-color: #442244;">Y</td>
      <td style="color: #FFFF00; background-color: #442244;">A</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="color: #FFEEFE; background-color: #990000;">Q</td>
      <td style="color: #FFFF00; background-color: #FF0;">M</td>
      <td style="color: #000000; background-color: #FF7777;">O</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: Great, but as this is printing to the console. I can use this to print to the HTML page too right ?  Would i use `document.write` ?

Comment: Yes you can, but never use `document.write()`. In jQuery you'd select the element then update it, eg. `$('#yourElement').html(arr.join(''));`

Comment: I updated the example above to give you a demo of that working

Comment: Hm i have tried that but i'm not getting any output below my table. Let me edit my main post to show you my new code

Comment: Make sure you're running the jQuery code when the DOM is ready, ie in a [`document.ready()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) event handler. I've updated the example again to give you the full thing. Also check the console for errors if you still have issues

Comment: Oh i see, i did also update my main code, what's the reason I can't run it like that. If i were to keep the start of my code with `function`

Comment: You could keep your logic in `getText()`, you just need to invoke that function from within the document.ready handler: `jQuery(function($) { getText(); });`

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
let concString = "";
$('table tbody').find('tr').each(function(){
  $(this).find('td').each(function(){
    // condition to get only visible td
    if($(this).css('background-color') !== $(this).css('color')){
      concString += $(this).text();
    }
  });
});

console.log(concString);
```